# Is there a way to set this type of dict to redis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I have a python dict in this format:

```py
expected_value = {
    'status': 'paid',
    'quantity': 1,
    'faturas': {
        'B68D736C0DF84C459DED3CD84F18E388': {
            'fatura_due_date': '2020-11-11',
            'customer_id': '0A9CA75877564E0894DAD774E0CB09DA'
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how (or if I can) set cache for this dict with some redis.Redis method. Can you help me?

Comment: Please explain more detailed what you are trying to do!

Comment: I have to set cache for a dict in this format, with nested dicts inside. I tried using redis.Redis.hset() but it doesn't seem to work with this redis method. Faturas is portuguese for invoices, so I have lots os invoices and I have to cache all of them and info about each one of them, that's why makes more sense to have nested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always getting and setting the entire object, you can get away with json-serializing your dict and using Redis's basic string type:

```
import json

r = redis.Redis()
r.set("my_key", json.dumps(expected_value))
```

and then, when fetching:

```
import json

r = redis.Redis()
val = r.get("my_key")
expected_value = json.loads(val)
```